# Compare the proportions of different groups for a sample with that of the population

Tags: chi-squared-test, proportion

I got a population which could be categorized into 4 groups. The population contains 169996 unit. The 4 groups contains 109881, 11318, 32242 and 16555 units respectively. And I also got a sample of 1733 units. The sample also could be categorized into 4 groups contain 1202, 63, 305 and 163 units respectively. The proportions of each group for the sample is:

```
c(1202, 63, 305, 163)/(1202+63+305+163)
# [1] 0.69359492 0.03635314 0.17599538 0.09405655
```

The proportions of each group for the population is:

```
c(109881, 11318, 32242, 16555)/(109881+11318+32242+16555)
# [1] 0.64637403 0.06657804 0.18966329 0.09738464
```

**I want to know whether the two proportions are significantly different from each other.** I searched a lot and fins the `chisq.test` function in R. Here is what I did:

```
chisq.test(c(1202, 63, 305, 163), p=c(109881, 11318, 32242, 16555)/(109881+11318+32242+16555))

#   Chi-squared test for given probabilities

# data:  c(1202, 63, 305, 163)
# X-squared = 31.662, df = 3, p-value = 6.167e-07
```

Am I doing it right?

I performed `chisq.test` for other samples and found that the p values given tend to be small. I am wondering if there is a more accurate approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is right. Chi-squared test just check if your sample can come out of your population and the result is plainly that it can't come from that population - according to the very small p-value.

If you look at your data, you can see that the second group has a frequency of about 6% on your population but just about 3% on your sample. With such a big sample that is a big difference. Just to double check you can do a proportion test on that category and p-value is also tiny:

```
> prop.test(x=c(63,11318),n=c(sum(c(1202, 63, 305, 163)),sum(c(109881,11318, 32242, 16555))))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(63, 11318) out of c(sum(c(1202, 63, 305, 163)), sum(c(109881, 11318, 32242, 16555)))
X-squared = 24.84, df = 1, p-value = 6.229e-07
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
-0.03940776 -0.02104202
sample estimates:
prop 1     prop 2 
0.03635314 0.06657804
```

Therefore, there is nothing wrong in your test, although there might be something wrong with your sampling method if your goal was to get a representative sample.

Disclaimer: The prop.test I did here was just with an illustrative purpose, because performing several tests on the same samples could lead to some problems. Please don't try to perform separate prop.tests on every group and draw serious conclusions from them.